# Pandas: how to change all the values of a column?

Tags: python, database, pandas

I have a data frame with a column called `"Date"` and want all the values from this column to have the same value (the year only). Example:

```
City     Date
Paris    01/04/2004
Lisbon   01/09/2004
Madrid   2004
Pekin    31/2004
```

What I want is:

```
City     Date
Paris    2004
Lisbon   2004
Madrid   2004
Pekin    2004
```

Here is my code:

```
fr61_70xls = pd.ExcelFile('AMADEUS FRANCE 1961-1970.xlsx')

#Here we import the individual sheets and clean the sheets    
years=(['1961','1962','1963','1964','1965','1966','1967','1968','1969','1970'])

fr={}

header=(['City','Country','NACE','Cons','Last_year','Op_Rev_EUR_Last_avail_yr','BvD_Indep_Indic','GUO_Name','Legal_status','Date_of_incorporation','Legal_status_date'])

for year in years:
    # save every sheet in variable fr['1961'], fr['1962'] and so on
    fr[year]=fr61_70xls.parse(year,header=0,parse_cols=10)
    fr[year].columns=header
    # drop the entire Legal status date column
    fr[year]=fr[year].drop(['Legal_status_date','Date_of_incorporation'],axis=1)
    # drop every row where GUO Name is empty
    fr[year]=fr[year].dropna(axis=0,how='all',subset=[['GUO_Name']])
    fr[year]=fr[year].set_index(['GUO_Name','Date_of_incorporation'])
```

*It happens that in my DataFrames, called for example `fr['1961']` the values of `Date_of_incorporation` can be anything (strings, integer, and so on), so maybe it would be best to completely erase this column and then attach another column with only the year to the DataFrames?*

Comment: Strings and numbers depending on whether there is only the year (like for Madrid in the example), or whether there is also the month and day (like for Pekin and Paris).

Answer (score 175):

As @DSM points out, you can do this more directly using the [vectorised string methods](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#vectorized-string-methods):

```
df['Date'].str[-4:].astype(int)
```

Or using extract (assuming there is only one set of digits of length 4 somewhere in each string):

```
df['Date'].str.extract('(?P<year>\d{4})').astype(int)
```

An alternative slightly more flexible way, might be to use [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html) (or equivalently [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html)) to do this:

```
df['Date'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda x: int(str(x)[-4:]))
             #  converts the last 4 characters of the string to an integer
```

The lambda function, is taking the input from the `Date` and converting it to a year.
You could (and perhaps should) write this more verbosely as:

```
def convert_to_year(date_in_some_format):
    date_as_string = str(date_in_some_format)  # cast to string
    year_as_string = date_in_some_format[-4:] # last four characters
    return int(year_as_string)

df['Date'] = df['Date'].apply(convert_to_year)
```

*Perhaps 'Year' is a better name for this column...*

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it is more complicated than that: sometimes the values are something else entirely (like characters). I think it wight be simpler to completely drop this column, and then add a new one with the year, or completely replace the values by the year.

Comment: @cbrunos Please could you provide an example where this doesn't work? (But you can adjust the `convert_to_year` to deal with it) ...I agree that a more appropriate name would be `df['Year']`.

Comment: @cbrunos This should work fine for you: `for year in fr: df=fr[year]; df['Year_of_incorporation']=df['Date_of_incorporation'].map(convert_to_year)`.

Comment: These days I often do things like `df["Date"].str[-4:].astype(int)`.

Comment: @DSM which is super neat... !

Comment: This is a fine solution if you are sure the year will always come last, and in 4 digits. If you can't assume that, you would have to use regular expressions `df["Date"].str.findall(r'\d{4}').str[0]` or a set of conditional expressions so you find the abbreviated 2 digit year within the date string.

Comment: @dmvianna or perhaps `s.str.extract('(?P<year>\d{4})')`

Comment: Oh, wow. I didn't know `str.extract` yet. Pleased to meet it!

Comment: new to python, but shouldn't `def convert_to_year(date_in_some_format);` be `def convert_to_year(date_in_some_format):` ?  I.e., a colon instead of a semi-colon.

Comment: @AndyHayden `.apply()` throwing the error: `SettingWithCopyWarning:


A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead  

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy`

Comment: Perhaps the 2nd line in the function should be `year_as_string = date_as_string[-4:]` instead?

Answer (score 34):

You can do a column transformation by using `apply`

Define a clean function to remove the dollar and commas and convert your data to float.

```
def clean(x):
    x = x.replace("$", "").replace(",", "").replace(" ", "")
    return float(x)
```

Next, call it on your column like this.

```
data['Revenue'] = data['Revenue'].apply(clean)
```

Answer (score 8):

Or if one want to use `lambda` function in the `apply` function:

```
data['Revenue']=data['Revenue'].apply(lambda x:float(x.replace("$","").replace(",", "").replace(" ", "")))
```