# Convert date column in dataframe to ticks in python

Tags: python, datetime, time

Good day

I have a pandas dataframe with 3 columns. Column two is in date format yyyy-mm-dd but I would like to convert these to ticks. I would like to know the most efficient way to do this (i.e. I don't want to loop through each row).

My code is as follows:

```
#Example of getting ticks
import time;  # This is required to include time module.

ticks = time.time()
print("Number of ticks since 12:00am, January 1, 1970:", ticks)

#Example of converting to ticks

import datetime
s = "01/12/2015"
time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(s, "%d/%m/%Y").timetuple())

#My code

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

path = "C:/Users/geoff/OneDrive - Noble Brothers Consult (Pty) Ltd/Clients/GrAM/Daily Price Data/"
filename = "SST_5_Sept_2016_formatted.csv"
full_path = path + filename

data = pd.read_csv(full_path)

#here i need to convert the column data['Date'] to ticks
```

I have uploaded a screenshot my datafile as well:

Screenshot of datafile:

[image: screenshot]

Thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, wrap the converting-to-ticks part in a function, such as

```
def convert_to_tic(s):
    return time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(s, "%d/%m/%Y").timetuple())
```

Then, turn your column into a `DataFrame` and use [apply](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html). Something in the likes of what is suggested in the bottom part of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12604909/pandas-how-to-change-all-the-values-of-a-column)

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: Is there a way in which we can convert "09/03/2014" this format to ticks