# How to modify DataFrame column without getting SettingWithCopyWarning?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `DataFrame` object `df`. And I would like to modify `job` column so that all retired people are 1 and rest 0 (like shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12604909/pandas-how-to-change-all-the-values-of-a-column)):

```
df['job'] = df['job'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x == "retired" else 0)
```

But I get a warning:

```
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

Why did I get it here though? From what I read it applies to situations where I take a slice of rows and then a column, but here I am just modyfing elements in a row. Is there a better way to do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to deal with SettingWithCopyWarning in Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas)

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
df['job']=df['job'].eq('retired').astype(int)
```

or

```
df['job']=np.where(df['job'].eq('retired'),1,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

So here's an example dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'job':['retired', 'a', 'b', 'retired']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

       job
0  retired
1        a
2        b
3  retired
```

Now, you can make use of numpy's [`where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) function:

```
df['job'] = np.where(df['job']=='retired', 1, 0)
print(df)

   job
0    1
1    0
2    0
3    1
```

Answer (score 0):

I would not suggest using apply here, as in the case of large data frame it could lower your performance.

I would prefer using `numpy.select` or `numpy.where`.

[See This](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) [And This](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)