# Update column under dataframe by regex

Tags: python

I have got a dataframe looks like this:

1. 12000 pa
2. 13000 per annum
3. 25000 pa
4. 34000 per annum

I need to update all four cells into int only, so:

1. 12000
2. 13000
3. 25000
4. 34000

What is the quickest method for doing this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas: how to change all the values of a column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12604909/pandas-how-to-change-all-the-values-of-a-column)

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible solutions:

`df["price_int"] = df["price"].apply(lambda value: int(value.split(" ")[0]))`

Or you can use Regex (more robust):

`df["price_int"] = df["price"].str.extract(r'(^[0-9]+)').astype(int)`